# Httpd (Apache) isn't refreshing sites

Tags: linux, apache

I have been using httpd (apache) for a while, but now for some reason if I do what I do I just can't refresh httpd. I have removed the files from /var/www/html, also moved them to /var/www, restarted the httpd.service several times, also restarted the pc and went so far that I reinstalled it, but for some reason it's still showing the same version of the site. And also when I stopped httpd.service the site was still accessible. I'm starting to think that it is just some really stupid thing but if even restart of pc didn't fix it, then it souldn't be just some stupidly easy problem.

Comment: Most likely, whatever machine you're editing, removing, stopping and starting things on *isn't actually the server for the site in question*.

Comment: @hobbs - It is it's running locally for now.